# How to implement a WebDriverEventListener in C#?

Tags: c#, selenium, testing, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests

How to implement `WebDriverEventListener` in C#?

I have no problem doing it in java importing:

```
import org.openqa.selenium.support.events.AbstractWebDriverEventListener;
```

However, `WebDriverEventListener` is not seen in C# and I cannot implement it.

Comment: What exactly do you want to achieve here.. can you clarify your question?

Comment: I have button that adds some element on page. After click on this button a request is sent to server and in response id of this element is sent. Each click element gets different id. I need to get this id to check in selenium if element of this ID apperas on page after click action.

Answer (score 6):

You have to add [Selenium.support.dll](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Selenium.Support/2.42.0) to your project.

Define and instantiate, event firing driver as below:

```
IWebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();

EventFiringWebDriver firingDriver = new EventFiringWebDriver(driver);
firingDriver.ElementClicked += new EventHandler<WebElementEventArgs>(firingDriver_ElementClicked);
```

For event to fire:

```
firingDriver.findElement(By.xpath("...").click();
```

Event is defined as:

```
private void firingDriver_ElementClicked(object sender, WebDriverExceptionEventArgs e) {
    // do action required to handle what happens after clicking button you have mentioned.
}
```

EventFiringDriver selenium source code is [here](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/source/browse/dotnet/src/support/Events/EventFiringWebDriver.cs) and its corresponding tests are [here](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/source/browse/dotnet/test/support/Events/EventFiringWebDriverTest.cs), for your reference.

Answer (score 6):

Event listening in the C# is accomplished by using the standard event mechanism exposed by the language. You create a method with the correct signature for the event, and attach it to the event. An example method would look like this:

```
void MyElementClickedHandler(object sender, WebElementEventArgs e)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Clicked");
}
```

Attaching the event would look something like this:

```
// Assumes driver is a properly created
// IWebDriver instance. 
IWebDriver eventDriver = new EventFiringWebDriver(driver);
eventDriver.ElementClicked += new EventHandler<WebElementEventArgs>(MyElementClickedHandler);
```

Inside the event handler method, the `EventArgs` parameter allows you to examine attributes associated with the event. In the case of an element event, the `EventArgs` will have a reference to the `IWebElement` the event fired on. To disconnect the event handler, you use the standard C# `-=` operator.

Answer (score 0):

This [link](http://waseemh.github.io/event-handling-selenium-webdriver/) gives a nice explanation of event handling for selenium:

The events mechanism in WebDriver is composed of two major objects:

**EventFiringWebDriver** - A wrapper of the normal WebDriver API but adds the support of event triggering.
**WebDriverEventListener** - An interface with pre-defined events that EventFiringWebDriver instance will trigger.

Implementation of Event handling in Selenium as Class Diagram:

[image]

**Step 1:** Create a class implementing WebDriverEventListener.

```
public class DefaultWebDriverEventListener implements WebDriverEventListener {

    public void beforeNavigateTo(String url, WebDriver driver) {
        System.out.println("Driver will navigate to:" + url);
    }

   ...
}
```

**Step 2:** Initalize event-firing driver using the webdriver instance you have created

```
//initalize FireFox webdriver instance
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
//initalize event-firing driver using Firefox webdriver instance.
EventFiringWebDriver eventDriver = new EventFiringWebDriver(driver);
```

**Step 3:** Register the listener

```
//register event listener to even-firing webdriver instance
eventDriver.register(listener);
```

Now all the defined events in your implemented class will be executed when the selenium is executing. For instance, taking screenshot on exception etc.

**Step 4:** You can also unregister the listener if you want to stop firing events when selenium

```
eventDriver.unregister(listener);
```

Comment: Thank you very much. This is really good explaination however do You know maybe how to implement it in C#?

Comment: Downvoting because the answer has nothing to do with the original question. The .NET event mechanism _is not_ like the Java mechanism, and the explanation, while correct for Java, does not address the question of .NET in any way.

Comment: @JimEvans, felt happy that, selenium contributor read my answer. I will post a C# related answer.

Answer (score 0):

Ensuring that webdriver intiated properly:

```
class WebDriverActionListener : EventFiringWebDriver
    {
 private IWebDriver _driver;

        public WebDriverActionListener(IWebDriver _driver): base(_driver)
        {
            this._driver = _driver;
            _driver.Manage().Timeouts().SetPageLoadTimeout(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(60));
        }

        protected override void OnElementClicking(WebElementEventArgs e)
        {
            _driver.Sync();
            string type = getTypeofElement(e.Element.TagName);
            base.OnElementClicking(e);
            Reporter.Logtofile("Clicked on element:" +e.Element.Text + " of type:" + type,Status.Info);
            _driver.Sync();
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

yet another simpler solution for site navigation.

1. Create & Register EventFiring driver

```
var driver = new ChromeDriver();
EventFiringWebDriver firingDriver = new EventFiringWebDriver(driver);
firingDriver.Navigating += FiringDriver_Navigating;
firingDriver.Navigated += FiringDriver_Navigated;
firingDriver.Navigate().GoToUrl(@"https://www.selenium.dev/");
```

2. Declare the Event

```
 private static void FiringDriver_Navigating(object sender, WebDriverNavigationEventArgs e)
{
    Console.WriteLine("NAVIGATING  - " + e.Url);
}

private static void FiringDriver_Navigated(object sender, WebDriverNavigationEventArgs e)
{
    Console.WriteLine("SITE LOADED - " + e.Url);
}
```