# Get notified about manually clicked links in Selenium WebDriver using C#

Tags: javascript, c#, selenium

I'm using the ChromeWebDriver together with Selenium. The application is partically controlled automatically. Now I want the user to navigate to a page, where he has to choose a link from some list like

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="http://google.de">Google</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://ecosia.org">Ecosia</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://yahoo.com">Yahoo</a></li>
</ul>
```

I want to get the link automatically, where the user clicked on. As example, when he clicks on *Google*, I need some kind of event, that gave me http://google.de in C#. There exist a [WebDriverEventListener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34678267/how-to-implement-a-webdrivereventlistener-in-c), his `ElementClicked` event is exactly what I need:

```
private void EventDriver_ElementClicked(object sender, WebElementEventArgs e) {
            if(e.Element.TagName == "a") {
                string link = e.Element.GetAttribute("href");
                MessageBox.Show($"User has clicked on link {link}");
            }
}
```

But the big problem here: `ElementClicked` is only fired on clicks triggered by Selenium using C#. All events have this issue. For example, `Navigated` got fired after calling `driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://stackoverflow.com")`, but not after manually clicking on a link in the browser.

To solve this, I think its necessary to forward client-side JS events. Like this pseudocode:

```
$('a').click(function() {
    SeleniumBackend.NotifyAboutClickEvent('a', $(this));
});
```

I know there is a method called `ExecuteScript` which allows to run JS in the browser. It seems possible to catch a direct return like

```
string jsReturnValue = driver.ExecuteScript("return 'test';");
```

For this case, that's not enough, since some sort of callback would be needed to be async.

```
object clickedLink = sharedWebDriver.ExecuteAsyncScript(@"
    var callback = arguments[arguments.length - 1];
    clickedLink('http://google.de');
");
```

That works, issue here: Only once. I can't bind an eventhandler, which notify me about later clicks...

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are creating the initial menu page. If that's true, you can just set a JS global variable using an `onlick` event and then use `JavascriptExecutor` to grab the variable setting and then use that to determine what link they clicked.

...or better yet, you can just detect the browser URL after they click and know where they went.