# c# Selenium wait till body class changes

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver

So i have this page that loads the items of a player

and it has

```
body class="">
```

A body class, now when I start the website it basically does this

```
body class="loading">
```

Now I want to put a 'wait' on my code untill the

```
body class="loading">
```

basically goes away and goes back to the empty class

Comment: Possible duplicate ? https://www.google.it/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34678267/how-to-implement-a-webdrivereventlistener-in-c&ved=2ahUKEwiBjaCSjfLaAhUHVRQKHW5tCzAQFjAAegQICRAB&usg=AOvVaw0p96ws9OE2NqACLFXCIE8I

Comment: @JacopoDT no I'm trying to do a negative wait.till

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I make sure if some HTML elements are loaded for Selenium + Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50154940/how-can-i-make-sure-if-some-html-elements-are-loaded-for-selenium-python)

Answer (score 0):

maybe this isn't the most elegant solution, it worked for me :

```
public void AttendreWhileBodyLoading()
{

  var myWait =new WebDriverWait(Driver.Instance, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));
  myWait.Until<IWebDriver>((d) =>
  {
    if (Driver.Instance.FindElements(By.ClassName("loading")).Count == 0)
    {
      return driver;
    }
    return null;
  });
}
```